# grunt cssmin preserve a non minified version

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

i'm using yeoman 1.0 rc and grunt for creating a static website, everithing is working fine, but i want to make besides the css minified version, a non minified version with all the filepaths updated, is that posible and how can i achive this.

the gruntfile is a very standart grunt file created by yo webapp.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
// load all grunt tasks
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
        options: {
            nospawn: true
        },
        coffee: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            tasks: ['coffee:dist']
        },
        coffeeTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            tasks: ['coffee:test']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app),
                        lrSnippet
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    open: {
        server: {
            path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },
    coffee: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        },
        test: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'test/spec',
                src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                dest: '.tmp/spec',
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        }
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            relativeAssets: false
        },
        dist: {
            options:{
                outputStyle: 'nested'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
    // check index.html to edit your build targets
    // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
    /*uglify: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                //collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*.html',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/images',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                src: [
                    'generated/*'
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'coffee:dist',
            'compass:server'
        ],
        test: [
            'coffee',
            'compass'
        ],
        dist: [
            'coffee',
            'compass:dist',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin',
            'htmlmin'
        ]
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'open',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'copy',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
```

};

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For production purpose you should always aim for the smallest amount of files (Because the most "expensive" (time wise) the HTTP is opening a connection, especially on mobile devises) and lowest file-size.
Meaning deploy the "dist" folder for production.

For testing purpose I usally deploy the "app" folder, because speed is not an issue here, an I would, as you write, like to be able to se exactly where in the code (css og js) the problems is.

So I would recogment just deploy the "app" folder until you are sure everything is as you want it.